# Prove that there exists a sequence of intermediate fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

How can I prove that for $K\subset L$ - the Galois extension of degree $p^n$, where $p$ is prime, there exists a sequence $K=K_{0}\subset K_{1}\subset \cdots \subset K_{n}=L$ such that $[K_{i}:K_{i-1}]=p$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $K\subset K_i$ is the Galois extension either?

I know that for Galois extensions the degree of the extension is equal to the number of intermediate subfields, but it doesn't imply that there exists the sequence mentioned above.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: By the main theorem of Galois theory, this is equivalent to a well-known group-theoretic statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the degree of the extension in general can be different from the number of intermediate subfields. For example, an extension of prime degree $p>2$ has no nontrivial subextensions!

To answer your question, notice that it is enough to show that there is a $K_{n-1}$ such that $[K\colon K_{n-1}]=p$, because then you proceed by induction since $[L\colon K]=[L\colon K_{n-1}][K_{n-1}\colon K]$. The existence of such a $K_{n-1}$ is guaranteed by group theory: a group of order $p^n$ has nontrivial center, hence by Cauchy's theorem it has a subgroup $H$ of order $p$ which is a subgroup of the center and therefore is normal. Then $K_{n-1}$ is just the fixed field of $H$.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. Thank you. To complete solution I'll add, that if we have the inclusions $K\subset K_{1}\subset K_{2}\subset L$ and both $K\subset K_{1}$ and $K_{1}\subset K_{2}$ are Galois, then $K\subset K_{2}$ is Galois as well.

Hope I am right.

Comment: This claim is in fact false, as you can take $K=\mathbb Q$, $K_1=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $K_2=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$. In fact you don't need it at all, because $K_{n-1}/K$ is Galois by the main theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: A true claim similar to yours is that if $L/K$ is Galois and some subextension $K_1/K$ is Galois, then also $L/K_1$ is Galois.

Comment: Ok. My mistake was that I forgot about an inverse including in the main theorem of the Galois Theory and tried to figure out why $K\subset K_{2}$ is Galois too. But actually the first subfield I find is $K_{n-1}$ not $K_{1}$, so I don't need to prove that $K\subset K_{2}$ is Galois indeed.